# Radio button checked not working in php

Tags: php

This is my code :

```
<td>
    <?php
      if ($adPropertyPayment == "Direct") {
          $checked = "checked = 'checked'";
      } else {
          $checked = "";
      }
      if ($adPropertyPayment == "CPC") {
          $checked = "checked = 'checked'";
      } else {
          $checked = "";
      }
      if ($adPropertyPayment == "CPM") {
          $checked = "checked = 'checked'";
      } else {
          $checked = "";
      }
    ?>

    <input type="radio" id="radioPaymentDirect"  name="payment" value="Direct" <?php echo $checked ?> onclick="showAmount('Direct');" />Direct 
    <input type="radio" id="radioPaymentCPC" name="payment" value="CPC" <?php echo $checked ?> onclick="showAmount('CPC');" />CPC
    <input type="radio" id="radioPaymentCPM" name="payment" value="CPM" <?php echo $checked ?> onclick="showAmount('CPM');" />CPM
</td>
```

Checked is not working. I am getting the value of `$aspropertypayment` in POST.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Did you do `$adPropertyPayment = $_POST['payment'];` anywhere? Also.. those if else statements are really strange. You are setting the same variable in every if statement. So your checkboxes will either all be checked or not.

Comment: This code lacks a lot of sense. Seems someone just brainlessly slapped it together, with no idea how it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
Use this
<?php
    $adPropertyPayment = $_POST['payment'];

    if ($adPropertyPayment == "Direct") {
        $checkedDir = "checked = 'checked'";
    } else {
        $checkedDir = "";
    }

    if ($adPropertyPayment == "CPC") {
        $checkedCpc = "checked = 'checked'";
    } else {
        $checkedCpc = "";
    }
    if ($adPropertyPayment == "CPM") {
        $checkedCpm = "checked = 'checked'";
    } else {
        $checkedCpm = "";
    }
    ?>
    <input type="radio" id="radioPaymentDirect"  name="payment" value="Direct" <?php echo $checkedDir;?> onclick="showAmount('Direct');" />Direct 
    <input type="radio" id="radioPaymentCPC" name="payment" value="CPC" <?php echo $checkedCpc;?> onclick="showAmount('CPC');" />CPC
    <input type="radio" id="radioPaymentCPM" name="payment" value="CPM" <?php echo $checkedCpm;?> onclick="showAmount('CPM');" />CPM
```

Comment: If by-default you would like to mark as checked before user submit the form you should use: $adPropertyPayment = (isset($_POST['payment']) && !empty($_POST['payment']))?$_POST['payment']:'Direct'; Or what are looking for?

Answer (score -1):

Try writting only $checked = 'checked'; in your if statement.

Comment: Why would that make any difference?